# Play 2.4 and Spring data JPA is not quite collaborating. Need solution

Tags: java, spring, playframework, spring-data-jpa, playframework-2.4

Play 2.4 supports Guice injection and I find it quite difficult to arrange the migration with Spring Data JPA.

Here are the few important links I have found but all have crutial limitations and incompleteness.

POC projects :

running quite well but it is on scala and I am searching for java

- https://github.com/jtdev/play-scala-spring-data-jpa
- https://github.com/jtdev/play-java-spring (limitations)
- https://github.com/zarinfam/play24-guice-spring (not so confident)

Now I want a serious discussion and solution on this. All these Value added projects are describing how incompatible these two projects are. Now what is important is we need a solution for these at lease with a deployment confidence. Please suggest what is the best way to incorporate these two?

Comment: Hello @Sagiruddin Mondal , so no one answered your question and I have the same issue. I found your solution at (https://github.com/beingsagir/play-java-spring-data-jpa); does it work for you, are there some serious limitations? Thanks!